# From NUMERIC to NVARCHAR in Netezza

Tags: netezza

How convert a value NUMERIC(18,0) to NVARCHAR(10) in Netezza?

I have the column GL2RDAP with a NUMERIC(18,0) value and I need to transform in NVARCHAR(10)

Answer (score 0):

to_char() function should do the trick

This is a link to the manual pages: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_conversion_funcs.html